# Can Functional Tests Replace Unit Tests in small projects

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, functional-testing

I am developing a new small project. I understand the importance of implementing automated tests to improve quality and maintainability. But I wander if in small applications the functional tests are sufficient. Is really necessary implement unit tests for all my functions? Do not functionality tests guaranty the quality of small applications?

Comment: You are talking about two things automation and functional tests. Functional testing can be done both manually and though automation. Go with automation only if there is sufficient ROI.

Comment: It is not necessary to test anything. If you can prove the code is correct. Or you do not care about quality.

Comment: To prove the correction of code is in most cases is very hard and time consuming. Nowadays is essential to have quality in software. So the only thing that rest is testing. No other solution to success in the software market.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on the size of the project and the number of "moving parts" involved; but generally speaking I would say that unit tests are at least as, if not more important than, functional tests.

I was going to give an analogy of a simple software system but instead I'll tell you a story which may or may not really have happened to me. No doubt I will be downvoted into oblivion for it, what can I say. YOLO.

Anyway so I'm on holidays, in a hotel, and I want to trim my luxurious and totally non-ironic beard using a really nice beard trimmer I brought with me.
*Except that the muppet that designed the bathroom put the only socket on the opposite side of the room to the mirror!* And to make things worse, the socket is the wrong shape because I'm in some weird foreign country where they drive on the wrong side of the road...

Not to worry. I have a travel power socket adapter. Except the cord on the trimmer is only 3 feet long and won't reach across the room. But wait! I have an extension cord, yay! Now I can preen myself in front of the mirror like a *real man*. **

I plug everything in and press the "on" button. The trimmer buzzes into life and then suddenly dies, leaving me with a lopsided mess of fuzz on my face.

*Quick: what is the problem?* Is it:

- The Socket
- My travel adapter
- The fuse on the trimmer plug
- The extension cord
- The trimmer
- The majestic awesomeness /horrendousness of my beard causing the trimmer to die on first contact?

**This** is the problem with only doing functional testing. Certainly by mucking around and switching things out I will eventually discover that the trimmer is working fine and the extension cord is the problem, but wouldn't it have been great if I had been able to check all of the bits and bobs involved in this operation **first** by Unit Testing them, so that even before I tried to turn on the trimmer, I knew that the cord was dodgy?

**this story is totally not true, I trim my beard with my shaving razor. Hell yeah.

Comment: Very good story to understand the benefits of unit testing. My problem in this project is trying to choose between, the cost of reengineering the software to accommodate unit tests (using mock frameworks and dependence injection frameworks), and not change the architecture and just implement automated functional tests. We are using MVC model and the .Net Entity framework. We just send the models generated by the entity framework to the controls. No view models and no business objects. To used mock classes and DI we have to do a lot of work. My question is, those changes will be useful or not?

Comment: @miguelbgouveia - Key question is: will the app change over time? e.g in 6 months time might you have to add in a business layer - then a unit testing investment will start to pay off, because this will drive a more modular design that promotes SRP and loose coupling, making it much easier to slot in new layers if required.

So if change is a possibility, then I would say very firmly "YES", there will be a tangible cost benefit in terms of developer and debug time saved.

However, if its not likely to change any time soon, then you will probably get away with just functional testing

Answer (score 1):

Functional tests might not be *small/unit* enough to catch implementation nuances at deep enough level.

While it's true they might cover enough ground to give you decent sense of confidence, you still might want to have unit tests to **track bugs**, **prevent regression** and deal with (problematic/rare) **edge cases**.

Besides, I don't see a need to introduce such distinction - functional vs unit vs integration vs what-not-else. You want *automated tests*, and that's all. You'll still have to implement them, most probably using same tools/frameworks for each test type.